# Adding Keyboard support to Java Swing application regardless of Focus

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, keyboard, keylistener

I have a `JFrame` with multiple panels that accumulates in a fairly complex Swing UI. I want to add Keyboard support so that *regardless* of component focus a certain Key press, for example the [ENTER] key, causes a listener to react.

I tried adding a `KeyListener` to the `JFrame` but that doesn't work if another `JComponent` is selected which changes focus.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: See [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: Some components have `ActionListeners` which react to `Enter` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registering a KeyEventDispatcher with the KeyboardFocusManager allows you to see all key events before they are sent to the focused component. You can even modify the event or prevent it from beeing delivered to the focused component:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(
    new KeyEventDispatcher() {
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            //Get the char which was pressed from the KeyEvent:
            e.getKeyChar();
            //Return 'true' if you want to discard the event.
            return false;
        }
    });
```

If you just want to get the key inputs for one window / component or just for specific keys, you can use KeyBindings as kleopatra suggested. As an example on how to register to the keyboard event on Enter pressed (You may use any VK_ provided by KeyEvent, for modifiers [alt, ctrl, etc.] see InputEvent) see:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //e.g.
JPanel content = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane(); 
content.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,0),"enterDown");
content.getActionMap().put("enterDown",new AbstractAction() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1l;
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //This action is called, as the Enter-key was pressed.
    }
});
```

Comment: don't use a chainsaw when a pocket knife can do the job ;-) KeyBindings in the parent are perfect here.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is to make the JFrame focusable and append the listener to it.  Then, iterate through all the JFrame children and make everything else not focusable. 
Of course this only works if you don't have text boxes or similar as they will become non editable.

Comment: no, that's the wrong approach - simply forget that keyListeners exist and learn how-to use keyBindings.